# I'm trying to generate a sell signal for the last 3 minutes of a trading day

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm have certain conditions for generating buy and sell signals and they work well. But I would like to generate a sell signal no matter what my other conditions are if it is the last bar of the day, so that I can start a new session fresh.
This is my code for doing this, it generates a sell signal for condition B or condition M, but not for condition t1. I am thinking that t1 is a Boolean, or am I wrong?

```
t1 = time(timeframe.period, "1557-1600:23456")
    
// to buy conditions
if B==true  and M==true  // to buy conditions 
    V5_Master_To_Buy := true
    V5_Master_To_Sell := false
    V5_Master_To_Sell

//to sell conditions 
else if B==false or M==false or t1==true
    V5_Master_To_Sell := true
    V5_Master_To_Buy := false
    V5_Master_To_Buy


// Only show markers on transitions.

plotshape(V5_Master_To_Buy and not V5_Master_To_Buy[1], title="V5_Master_To_Buy", location=location.belowbar, color=color.lime, style=shape.triangleup, textcolor=color.yellow, text="BUY")            
plotshape(V5_Master_To_Sell and not V5_Master_To_Sell[1], title="V5_Master_To_Sell", location=location.abovebar, color=color.yellow, style=shape.triangledown, textcolor=color.yellow, text="SELL")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Indeed your t1 variable will always return true like this

```
BarInSession(sess) => not na(t1)
in_session = BarInSession("1557-1600")
if in_session
    // generate sell signal
```

Keep also in mind the time() function allows to specify the timezone you want too with the third parameter
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_time

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Tried this, but still don't get the sell signal:     `t1 = time(timeframe.period, "1557-1600:23456")
BarInSession(sess) => not na(t1)
in_session = BarInSession("1557-1600")

    // generate sell signal

// to buy conditions
if B==true  and M==true  // to buy conditions 
    V5_Master_To_Buy := true
    V5_Master_To_Sell := false
    V5_Master_To_Sell

//to sell conditions 
else if B==false or M==false or in_session
    V5_Master_To_Sell := true
    V5_Master_To_Buy := false
    V5_Master_To_Buy`

Comment: I have the right timezone, because I can plotshape the t1 and that shows on the last bar of the day, but not the SELL signal

Comment: could you please add your entire script to your StackOverflow post?
I need to understand everything to help you properly :)

Comment: @deveatt Hi , the entire code is 350 lines long, are you sure you want to read through that?

Comment: not that I want to :) 
But there is no other way for someone helping you than getting the whole context/code